# wglMakeCurrent error: 00000006 when I run menu driver program in OpenGL in Cygwin

Tags: c, opengl, cygwin, freeglut, xserver

I get this wglMakeCurrent error: 00000006
in Cygwin everytime I run an application that has menu items in OpenGL. For the first time it works perfectly but the second time onwards, instead of menu, I see black rectangle in Window and see wglMakeCurrent error: 00000006
in Cygwin.

**Note:** The same code works exactly as it should when I run it Dev-C++.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
static int window;
static int menu_id;
static int submenu_id;
static int value = 0;
float x1 = 200.0, y1 = 200.0, x2 = 100.0, y2 = 300.0, x3 = 200.0, y3 = 400.0, x4 = 300.0, y4 = 300.0;
void draw_pixel(int x, int y)
{
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2i(x, y);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}
void edgedetect(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, int *le, int *re)
{
float mx, x, temp;
int i;
if ((y2 - y1)<0) // y1>y2 ie. Y1=400 ,y2=300
{
temp = y1; y1 = y2; y2 = temp;
temp = x1; x1 = x2; x2 = temp;
}
if ((y2 - y1) != 0) //not a horizontal line
mx = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
else mx = x2 - x1;
x = x1;
for (i = y1; i <= y2; i++)
{
if (x<(float)le[i])
le[i] = (int)x;
if (x>(float)re[i])
re[i] = (int)x;
x += mx;
}
}
void scanfill(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float x4, float y4)
{
int le[500], re[500], i, y;
for (i = 0; i<500; i++)
{
le[i] = 500;
re[i] = 0;
}
edgedetect(x1, y1, x2, y2, le, re);
edgedetect(x2, y2, x3, y3, le, re);
edgedetect(x3, y3, x4, y4, le, re);
edgedetect(x4, y4, x1, y1, le, re);
for (y = 0; y<500; y++)
{
if (le[y] <= re[y])
for (i = (int)le[y]; i<(int)re[y]; i++)
draw_pixel(i, y);
}
}
void menu(int num){
if (num == 0)
{
glutDestroyWindow(window);
exit(0);
}
else{
value = num;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
void createMenu(void)
{
submenu_id = glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("scanfill polygon", 2);
menu_id = glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("Clear", 1);
glutAddSubMenu("Draw", submenu_id);
glutAddMenuEntry("Quit", 0);
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
}
void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
if (value == 1)
{
return; //glutPostRedisplay();
}
else if (value == 2)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex2f(x1, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y2);
glVertex2f(x3, y3);
glVertex2f(x4, y4);
glEnd();
scanfill(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);
glFlush();
} }
void myinit()
{
glClearColor(0.17, 0.13, 0.4, 1.0);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0, 499.0, 0.0, 499.0);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
window = glutCreateWindow("Menu driven Programming for Scan filling ");
createMenu();
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
myinit();
glutMainLoop();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Menu:

[image: Menu]

After selecting menu subitem to fill polygon:

[image: After selecting menu subitem to fill polygon]

Error on Cygwin Terminal:

[image: Error on Cygwin Terminal]

Output in Dev-C++:

[image: Output in Dev-C++]

Comment: the error does not show up if the server is run without the GL hardware accelerator with `startxwin -- -nowgl` . So it is possible a driver issue

Comment: @matzeri Thank you, it worked but It showed ```libGL error: Windows-DRI extension not available``` but the menu is working fine. Thank you and you could possibly post it as an answer. This also explains why my cube was rotating so fast in Cygwin and normally in Ubuntu. After using ```startxwin -- -nowgl``` , The cube is rotating at normal speed as it was in Ubuntu.